# How to append a stylesheet to <head> in AngularJS $routeProvider?

Tags: css, angularjs, conditional-statements, route-provider

I want to load a specific CSS file only when a user accesses the `contact.html` view on my AngularJS app/site. I found this answer which almost made sense to me [How to include view/partial specific styling in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs) The accepted answer by charlietfl reads :

> Could append a new stylesheet to head within `$routeProvider`. For
>   simplicity am using a string but could create new link element also,
>   or create a service for stylesheets
>
> ```
> /* check if already exists first - note ID used on link element*/
> /* could also track within scope object*/
> if( !angular.element('link#myViewName').length){
>     angular.element('head').append('<link id="myViewName" href="myViewName.css" rel="stylesheet">');
> }
> ```
>
> Biggest benefit of prelaoding in page is any background images will
>   already exist, and less lieklyhood of `FOUC`

The problem is that I do not know exactly where in my `$routeProvider` to add the code. charlietfl mentions where to put it in a comment which reads

> not if the when for the route hasn't been called. Can put this code in
>   controller callback of when within the routeProvider, or perhaps
>   within resolve callback which likely triggers sooner

I have modified my `$routeProvider` following the advice. I added a `resolve` in the object following `.when('/contact'`. Here is my code

```
angular.module('maxmythicApp', ['ngResponsiveImages'])
  .config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/design.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/design', {
        templateUrl: '/views/design.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/views/contact.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: 
          if( !angular.element('link#myViewName').length){
            angular.element('head').append('<link id="myViewName" href="myViewName.css" rel="stylesheet">');
          }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Would this work?

Comment: You have to use `$compile' to let angular know that you have to add something to the dom. This should automatically call $scope.$apply() which inturn would call $$digest. This should do the trick.

Comment: Where exactly would I place `$compile`?

Answer (score 9):

I made a service for it.

Important part of the code :

```
var head = angular.element(document.querySelector('head')); // TO make the code IE < 8 compatible, include jQuery in your page and replace "angular.element(document.querySelector('head'))" by "angular.element('head')"

if(head.scope().injectedStylesheets === undefined)
{
    head.scope().injectedStylesheets = [];
    head.append($compile("<link data-ng-repeat='stylesheet in injectedStylesheets' data-ng-href='{{stylesheet.href}}' rel='stylesheet' />")(scope)); // Found here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11913182/1662766
}

head.scope().injectedStylesheets.push({href: "/url/to/style.css"});
```

Full code in Github : https://github.com/Yappli/angular-css-injector)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**: [Here is the solution to inject(load) a specific CSS using the $routeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511167/1310945).

***The solution described below is an alternative to apply different classes and page title based on the route which could be used in other situations.***

For each route I've created a new key called '**bodyClass**' and '**title**' (but you could called anything you like it) and it looks like this:

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', 'ngResource'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {

myApp.siteName = 'My Cool App';

$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
     title:'Home - ' + myApp.siteName,
     bodyClass: 'home',
     templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
     controler: 'bmsHomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
      title:'Contact - ' + myApp.siteName,
      bodyClass: 'contact',
      templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
      controler: 'bmsContactCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

Then for each $routeChangeSuccess event I change the `<title>` of the page and also the class of the `<body>`.

```
myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {

      if (current.$$route) {

        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;

        $rootScope.bodyClass = current.$$route.bodyClass;
      }
    });
}]);
```

You put the code above on the same main **app.js** (for example) file.

On my index.html page, which renders the views, I have the following codes to pick up the title and class:

```
<title>{{ title }}</title>

<body class="{{ bodyClass }}">
```

So if i visit the home page of my application the title tag will be

```
<tittle> Home - My Cool App</tittle>
```

and the body tag will be

```
<body class="home">
```

It's working like a charm.

I know this solution doesn't load a CSS file, but you could put those styles inside a '**.contact**' class that is **applied** only when you hit a specific route.

Not sure if solves your problem but I hope that helps or at least point you on the right direction.

Comment: The css in the .contact class will be loaded with the rest of the main css when that resource is requested. It doesn't get loaded dynamically, but applied dynamically.

Comment: @AGDM that's correct. And what I have described above is also correct! :) Maybe the word "loaded" is a bit misleading. So I am happy to change it to "applied".

Answer (score 2):

For a full solution I suggest using [AngularCSS](https://github.com/door3/angular-css).

As you already know, in Angular we can include templates (structure) and controllers (behavior) in pages and components. AngularCSS enables the last missing piece: attaching stylesheets (presentation).

Routes example:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/page1', {
  templateUrl: 'page1/page1.html',
  controller: 'page1Ctrl',
  /* Now you can bind css to routes */
  css: 'page1/page1.css'
})
.when('/page2', {
  templateUrl: 'page2/page2.html',
  controller: 'page2Ctrl',
  /* You can also enable features like bust cache, persist and preload */
  css: {
    href: 'page2/page2.css',
    bustCache: true
  }
})
.when('/page3', {
  templateUrl: 'page3/page3.html',
  controller: 'page3Ctrl',
  /* This is how you can include multiple stylesheets */
  css: ['page3/page3.css','page3/page3-2.css']
})
.when('/page4', {
  templateUrl: 'page4/page4.html',
  controller: 'page4Ctrl',
  css: [
    {
      href: 'page4/page4.css',
      persist: true
    }, {
      href: 'page4/page4.mobile.css',
      /* Media Query support via window.matchMedia API
       * This will only add the stylesheet if the breakpoint matches */
      media: 'screen and (max-width : 768px)'
    }, {
      href: 'page4/page4.print.css',
      media: 'print'
    }
  ]
});
```

Directive example:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-directive/my-directive.html',
    css: 'my-directive/my-directive.css'
  }
});
```

You can read more about AngularCSS [here](http://door3.com/insights/introducing-angularcss-css-demand-angularjs):

http://door3.com/insights/introducing-angularcss-css-demand-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I think the best/simplest answer is one I left [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404559/1313904). Someone else asked the same question, so I came up with some simple code and a small github repo to handle this scenario.