# How to organise styles in angularjs singlepage application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, single-page-application, singlepage

I'm trying to create a singlepage angular application, but I don't know, how to load styles for particular controller view, if controller scope can only be applied in body element.

Here is the base layout of whole angular application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <link href="/styles/some-basic-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/custom/app.js"></script>
</head>
<ng-view></ng-view>
</html>
```

That app.js routing:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/somepage', {templateUrl: 'views/someView.html', controller: 'someController'});
 $routeProvider
    .when('/anotherpage', {templateUrl: 'views/anotherView.html', controller: 'anotherController'});
});
```

An example view:

```
<body ng-controller="someController">
    <!--some html code here-->
<script src="/scripts/someController.js"></script>
</body>
```

So, how can I change page title or add styles/scripts in my views if it's only accessible from global tamplate?

I think that I misunderstood something or I have to learn something else about angular, but what is that? Thanks for any help!

Comment: good solution here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490882/how-to-append-a-stylesheet-to-head-in-angularjs-routeprovider

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, you can define a ng-controller over the `html` like `RootController` and then achieve whatever you want using the standard angular binding.

If that does not work, then there is always `$rootScope`. Properties\methods defined on `$rootScope` are accessible anywhere inside `ng-app`.

Comment: I think the second option is better and it can help me with titles. But I don't see, how can it help me with styles injection in head of maintemplate?

Comment: How do you want style to get injected. Give an example?

Comment: Like that: 

    <ng-styles>
        <link ref="styles.css" rel="styleshett" type="text/css" />
</ng-styles>
<body ng-controller="someController">
    <!--some html code here-->
    <script src="/scripts/someController.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: `ng-style` does not work this way, but you can always select style sheet dynamically, such as `<link href="/styles/{{stylesheetname}}.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. Or set `ng-style` on individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

For the title you can do in the controller
like

```
$window.document.title = 'My title';
```

or better set up a service like

```
app.factory('WindowUtils', function($window) {
        return {
           setTitle:function(str){
              $window.document.title = str;
           }
        }
    })
```

for the style I don't understand the trouble because of you can put
all the styles in your styles.css globaly for the whole application.