# AngularJS : dynamic stylesheet link tag fires request too soon

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm facing an issue similar (but not identical, please bear with me) to the one described in [Conditionally-rendering css in html head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912330)

I'm also "lazily" loading a stylesheet, getting the filename from a scope variable that I initialize at the very beginning of my controllers :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-href="css/{{ filename }}.css" />
```

As I'm using `ng-href` (here in its `data-` form), I'm indeed avoiding unwanted requests such as :

```
http://localhost/css/%7B%7B%20filename%7D%7D.css
```

But it all still fires too soon, and I'm getting this almost every time :

```
http://localhost/css/.css
```

Which seems to mean the request fires **between** the moment when Angular removes its own markup and the moment it replaces it with the correct value (which it does, a moment later, and then my stylesheet loads properly). I reckon it's not even possible...!?

I figured I might be providing a value for the `filename` scope variable too late, but as I said, it's the first thing done in my controller :

```
angular.module('myControllers', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.filename = 'test';

        // some more code...
    }]);
```

I'm using Angular 1.1.5 ; is there anything I can do about it ? It's not that big of a deal, but it would still be better if I could fix it.

**EDIT :** Here comes the complete code, as requested. I won't include page templates as they are irrelevant regarding the issue.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-href="/assets/css/{{ filename }}.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="app" style="display: none;" data-ng-view></div>

    <script src="/assets/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app/controllers.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['myControllers'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);

app.run();
```

controllers.js :

```
angular.module('myControllers', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.filename = 'stylesheet';
    }]);
```

(Yes, I tried with an empty controller just like this one, same issue.)

Comment: Does this behavior occur in the body as well? Are you sure it's a head thing?

Comment: @Phix : I just tried moving the link tag into the body, the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Where is your controller scope bound in your markup?

Comment: @AndréDion : Do you mean using ngController ? I have two controllers in the app so I'm not using this directive (controllers are bound via $routeProvider).

Sorry, I'm still discovering Angular so maybe I'm not answering it right...?

Comment: You can bind your controller scope using the `ng-controller` directive or from your `$routeProvider` config. I'm also fairly green to Angular, but I suspect your `<link>` element is not actually part of your controller's scope. Does `{{filename}}` ever get expanded to the correct value?

Comment: Yes, it finally does. The request I want to cancel is an extra one, as the correct one happens when the filename variable gets populated correctly by Angular.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle / plunkr that emulates this behavior?

Comment: Here's a plunkr, but I can't reproduce the issue on it. It happened the very first time and not since, so it may be a loading-related thing. http://plnkr.co/edit/gCDRHEpsUQ0IUPtoW1AI?p=preview

Comment: If you cache-clear refresh (shift f5) does it happen? I can't say I've had this happen to me using angular before, and considering your code is pretty straight forward..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by adding an `ngIf` directive to the `link` tag, so it's not rendered until `filename` isn't falsy. Kinda dirty I know, but it actually works !

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-if="filename" data-ng-href="css/{{ filename }}.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in a small example.

That the algo:

```
attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {
      if (!value)
         return;

      attr.$set(attrName, value);

      // on IE, if "ng:src" directive declaration is used and "src" attribute doesn't exist
      // then calling element.setAttribute('src', 'foo') doesn't do anything, so we need
      // to set the property as well to achieve the desired effect.
      // we use attr[attrName] value since $set can sanitize the url.
      if (msie) element.prop(attrName, attr[attrName]);
    });
```

The function immediately returns if that value is false e.g. undefined.

Could you post the complete code,
the should be another problem.

Edit:

Binding a Controller via the Route-Provider only binds this controller to your element with the ng-view element.

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<head ng-controller="HeadCtrl">
<link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-href="{{ filename }}.css">
</head>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("HeadCtrl",function ($scope)
{
$scope.filename = 'apartment';
});
```

Comment: Nice one. The problem is I can have multiple controllers which will each bring their own stylesheet (as I give the filename variable the right value in each of them). So a separate controller to handle this doesn't look good in my case.

But the scope used to be an issue indeed, which is why I'm actually using $rootScope (cf. the complete code I added by editing my post).

Comment: @neemzy If that's the case, keep the `HeadCtrl` as suggested by Robin and create a service that controllers can use to set a property on the service. Check out this video on [Sharing Data between Controllers](http://www.egghead.io/video/HXpHV5gWgyk).

Comment: @AndréDion Thanks for the link ! I still have the same issue though, so I'm not convinced it's scope-related (using $rootScope pretty much avoids this kind of issue anyway, even if it's indeed a dirty way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Btw

ng-cloak not 'fires' to hide something.
You have to add a CSS class for it.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

```
[ng\:cloak], 
[ng-cloak], 
[data-ng-cloak], 
[x-ng-cloak], 
.ng-cloak, 
.x-ng-cloak {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Don't to inline css please :)

Its a simple directive that removes the ng-cloak attribute when angular finished loading and starts interpreting the directives.

Then your code switched to visible via normal browser-render mechanisms.

Comment: Haha, I'm no fan of inline CSS either. I'll give it another shot using the class syntax directly.

Comment: I tried again and it still doesn't work. All my JS is at the bottom of the body, so my markup is rendered before it gets executed and the ng-cloak class means anything, that may be why ?