# How to use ng-repeat or othe angularjs expressions in <head> tag

Tags: angularjs

I am on the early steps toward Learning Angularjs as a frontend framework, and I want to feed my index page dynamically with css rules that will be inserted into the  of the page under the  tag, I don't know if it is possible to use ng-repeat inside style tag or not, Because I don't want to use the inline css style on html element .

Example : 
I have many @font-face rules (tokens) that I want to declare in the  dynamically then I can apply the style="font-family:whatever,serif" to the html element.

Here is controller.js

```
var fontsApp = angular.module('fontsApp', []);
fontsApp.controller('FontsListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('fonts.php').success(function(data) { 
 $scope.styles = JSON.parse(data.css); 

  });

 });
```

And this is the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html   ng-app="fontsApp" ng-controller="FontsListCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title></title>

    <script src="js/angular-1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css" ng-repeat="rule in styles" >

    I want to Repeat the Css rules here 
         {{rule.css}}

    </style>
</head>
<body >
```

This is not working . How Can I do it using Angularjs  ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? What have you tried? What is your code, your expected output, and your actual output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS : conditionally rendering css in html head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912330/angularjs-conditionally-rendering-css-in-html-head)

Comment: No, It is not the same question , the link you added is about rendering a <link > tag to external file not repeating inside a tag

Comment: The correct expression would be `{{ rule }}`. Not `{{styles.rule}}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, For anyone has this problem and looking for simple answer, the best answer I found to solve this issue is to create a directive and bind it to templateUrl.

```
fontsApp.directive('stylekom', function() {
var directive = {}; 
directive.restrict = 'A'; /* restrict this directive to Attribute */
directive.templateUrl = "fonts.css";

return directive;
});
```

and in your html file add a new head element called , with an attribute called stylekom which is identical to the directive we have created in the above code .

```
<style stylekom></style>
```

Now the file fonts.css should be created using the php script in fonts.php