# CSS File: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have included a css file into my AngularJS Application like I did with other css files. With other css files it works fine but with the management.css file I got the follwoing exception in the picture and I don't know why.
Does anybody any hint what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks a lot!

[EDIT]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/management/common/management.service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/management/core/management.routes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/management/management/management.controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/management/management/management.css"></script>
```

[image: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.']

```
.management .management-name {
font-weight: bold;
}
.management .management-username {
font-style: italic;
}
.management .management-email {
color: #ccc;
}
.management .managementSearchUser {
color: #a00;
}
.management .management-search-result {
font-size: 1.2em;
}
.management .management-found-user-edit {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you used to include the file. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912330/conditionally-rendering-css-in-html-head/11913182#11913182) might also be useful.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="" /> ensure this, have you declared css like?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="app/management/management/management.css"></script>` is not how you include a css file

Comment: what a stupied fault! - Thanks for help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your import declaration is wrong you should use:

```
<link href="app/management/management/management.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: i would have made a bet that i cant do such nasty mistake. In my case I used script tag for css importing...Gosh!!! Thanks Fam. you saved my day!

Answer (score 7):

You have included the external CSS file using

```
<script src="app/management/management/management.css"></script>
```

Instead you have to  include it using

```
<link href="app/management/management/management.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```